# How to stamp circles to 2d np arrays with addup values

Tags: python, arrays

I want to stamp circles on an image, in which duplicate might happen in pt_list and overlap may happen among circles, but my method is very very slow since I used for loop. Does anyone know how to accelerate it with integrated iterations such as `np.meshgrid`

```
def stamp_circle(img, pt_list,r,addup):
    x = np.arange(0,img.shape[1])
    y = np.arange(0,img.shape[0])
    for pt in pt_list:
        mask = (x[np.newaxis,:]-pt[1])**2 + (y[:,np.newaxis]-pt[0])**2 < r**2
        img[mask] += addup
```

`img` is a 2d np array (4096x8192), `pt_list` is an array with the chosen point with the shape of (1224,2), `r` is the radius in pixels, and `addup` is the brightness I want to stamp on the elements of the circles.

Comment: you could at least calculate `r**2` only once - before `for`-loop

Comment: maybe first you should use `profiler` or at least `print()` with `time` to check which calculation makes long time. Maybe you could make some calcuations  only once - before `for`-loop - like `r**2`